# Как изменить цвет столбика диаграммы на листе Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, диаграммы

Есть диаграмма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу программно изменить цвет **первого** столбца на зеленый, чтобы в итоге получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал разные способы:

```
ChartObject chartObject = sheet.ChartObjects(@"Диаграмма1");
Excel.Series ser = (Excel.Series)chartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection(1);
ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
ser.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
ser.Format.Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
ser.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = (int)Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня, как видите, получается только цвет контура изменить. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ оказался:

```
series.Points(1).Interior.Color = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
ser.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(chartColor);
```

Comment: попробовал `ser.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);` выдает тоже самое - окрашивает контур в красный цвет.